# Cant launch application using JAVAFX FXML file

Tags: javafx, controller, program-entry-point, fxml, launch

I am trying to launch the IntLogin window from the main class (MAAWB); however, I can not seem to get it to launch. My splash screen launches without issues. I ran a debug with no issues until it hits the launch sequence then it kicks back an unrecognizable error. I have included below the main, fxml and controller file. What am I missing or doing wrong here that's causing me all these headaches? Also if anyone has the answer how do I put my splash screen on a timer?

main

```
package javafxswingapplication3;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Preloader;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class MAAWB extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Parent root;
    try {
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Intlogin.fxml"));
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle("initial login");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 222, 484));
   stage.show();

} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Preloader.launch(MAAWBPreloader.class, args);
    Application.launch(MAAWB.class, args);



}

}
```

fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="222.0" prefWidth="484.0"     xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"     fx:controller="javafxswingapplication3.IntloginController">
   <children>
  <TextField layoutX="173.0" layoutY="50.0" />
  <TextField fx:id="username" editable="false" layoutX="173.0" layoutY="90.0" />
  <ChoiceBox layoutX="173.0" layoutY="130.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="187.0" />
  <Label layoutX="91.0" layoutY="55.0" text="Installation" />
  <Label layoutX="94.0" layoutY="95.0" text="Username" />
  <Label layoutX="58.0" layoutY="135.0" text="Functional Area" />
  <Button cancelButton="true" layoutX="400.0" layoutY="182.0"     mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cancel" />
  <Button layoutX="327.0" layoutY="182.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Submit" />
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

controller

```
package javafxswingapplication3;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.Properties;
import static javafx.application.ConditionalFeature.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class IntloginController implements Initializable {

private TextField username;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    final String UN = System.getProperty("user.name");

    username.setText(UN);
}    

}
```

error

```
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at javafxswingapplication3.MAAWB.start(MAAWB.java:31)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javafxswingapplication3.IntloginController.initialize(IntloginController.java:28)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "an unrecognizable error"?

Comment: The compiler kicks back "error variable unrecognizable"

Comment: The compiler? I thought you said you were running this, and then you got an error. Which line gives the compile error?

Comment: Sorry for the miss communication, the error does happen when running. There are no issues with the build at all.

Comment: So can you post the stack trace in your question? Which line throws the exception?

Comment: It throws an exception from the FXMLLoader.java, not from my code. I put the list up above, hope that helps.

Comment: "Caused by NullPointerException at IntLoginController.java:28". So which is line 28?

Comment: line 28: public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

Comment: Not possible. Have you modified the code since you generated the stack trace? Save and run it again and see if it still tells you line 28.

Comment: The Exception: at javafxswingapplication3.IntloginController.initialize(IntloginController.java:28) here is the corresponding line: username.setText(UN); }

Comment: Please do not ask unrelated questions such as "how do I put my splash screen on a timer?", within a single question; i.e., one question per question.

Comment: Thanks James_D and jewelsea for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate the username definition [@FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXML.html).

```
@FXML
private TextField username;
```

This will associate the TextField defined in your controller with the textfield defined in your FXML via `fx:id="username"`.

Comment: wow, I feel completely dumb. Thanks a lot for your help, I completely forgot to add it in.